# Double mixing time convergence

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given a Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ and stationary distribution $\pi$. Suppose $T$ is the mixing time of the chain, meaning that if we start from any state $s$ from the state set $S$, then the distribution $\pi_t$ after $t$ steps is such that $\frac12\sum_{s\in S}|\pi_t(s)-\pi(s)|\le\frac14$.

Is it true that after $2t$ steps, we will have $\frac12\sum_{s\in S}|\pi_{2t}(s)-\pi(s)|\le\frac{1}{16}$?

Comment: I think the last "$\pi_t$" should be "$\pi_{2t}$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the best possible bound is $\tfrac18.$ Consider a two-state Markov chain with self-loop probabilities $\tfrac 3 4.$ The unique stationary distribution $\pi$ is uniform: probability $\tfrac 1 2$ for each state. In terms of transition matrices, the transition matrix for two steps is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\tfrac 3 4&\tfrac 1 4\\
\tfrac 1 4&\tfrac 3 4
\end{pmatrix}^2
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\tfrac 5 8&\tfrac 3 8\\
\tfrac 3 8&\tfrac 5 8
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Starting at either state we have $\frac12\sum_{s\in S}|\pi_1(s)-\pi(s)|=\frac14$ but $\frac12\sum_{s\in S}|\pi_2(s)-\pi(s)|=\frac18.$

---

To show that $\tfrac18$ is a bound, let $\pi_t^x(s)$ denote the probability of being at $s$ starting at $x$ after $t$ steps, and note that

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{s\in S}|\pi_{2t}(s)-\pi(s)|\\
&=\sum_{s\in S}\left| \sum_{x\in S}(\pi_t^x(s)-\pi(s))(\pi_t(x)-\pi(x))\right|\\
&\leq\sum_{s\in S}\sum_{x\in S}|\pi_t^x(s)-\pi(s)|\cdot |\pi_t(x)-\pi(x)|\\
&\leq \tfrac14.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok. Do you know that $1/8$ is really the best possible bound?

Comment: @Karo: I've added an argument showing that $1/8$ is a bound